# How can i screenshot website using puppeteer and send it into message Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, puppeteer

I want to screenshot webiste and that screenshot to send in message discord when command is runned.
I messed up and don't know what to do

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


module.exports = class LinkCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('link', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.hltv.org/team/5995/g2#tab-matchesBox');
    
    console.log(await page.content());
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
    
    await browser.close();
    
        message.channel.send(`${screenshot} je`)
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Errors? Can you br more specific on *I messed up*

Comment: when i run code. I get error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Comment: i tried extending time but its not working.
and i am not sure what shouild i put in message.channel.send(``) so it can show image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a path to puppeteer, the image will be returned as [binary data](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) ([source](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions)) which can be sent directly (see DiscordJS' [fileOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FileOptions)):

```js
let screenshot = await page.screenshot(); 
await browser.close();
message.channel.send("Screenshot", {files: [screenshot]});
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Comment: @LZ Are you sure you passed the screenshot as array? `files: [screenshot]`. Because I just tested it and it worked. ([See here](https://imgur.com/WseqGRK))

Comment: yeah it was my internet connection problem.
I just putted :
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

and it fixed it